# MySQL group by sum issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have 2 tables:

```
prueba
cod varchar(25)   PK
nom varchar(100)
tip varchar(50)
des varchar(500)
pre double
can double
cla varchar(3)
fcm varchar(20)
```

and

```
inventario
loc varchar(20)
cod varchar(25) FK
can double
cve varchar(3)
```

The tables are related by cod.
I have this MySQL query:

```
select inventario.cod as 'Código', inventario.can as 'Cantidad', inventario.cve as 'Clave', prueba.nom as 'Descripción', prueba.tip as 'Modelo', prueba.pre as 'Precio'
from inventario, prueba
where inventario.loc = 'XTORR' 
group by inventario.cod
order by inventario.cod ;
```

And it returns these results:

```
Código can cve  Descripción               Modelo Precio
20121   2   S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2        199
20122   1   S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2        199
20124   2   S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2        199
2014    4   S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2        199
2015    1   F   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2        199
```

The problem is that 2014 and 2015 are not suming up their values with the group by

```
XTORR   2014    4   S
XTORR   2014    2   S
XTORR   2015    1   F
XTORR   2015    1   F
```

2014 should have 6 in can, and 2015 should have 2. But, if I use the sum() for inventario.can the can values rocket up.

```
select inventario.cod as 'Código', sum(inventario.can) as 'Cantidad', inventario.cve as 'Clave', prueba.nom as 'Descripción', prueba.tip as 'Modelo', prueba.pre as 'Precio'
from inventario, prueba
where inventario.loc = 'XTORR' 
group by inventario.cod
order by inventario.cod ;

20121   3456    S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2       199
20122   1728    S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2       199
20124   3456    S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2       199
2014    10368   S   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2       199
2015    3456    F   FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2       199
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried DISTINCT?

Comment: can you post the data in the two tables.. your getting the Cartesian Product of the two tables and it needs to be filtered

Comment: How are these tables related? Please identify Primary and Foreign keys.

Comment: Though [`MySQL` **extension**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) makes your code valid, you still need to learn what information is returned for non-aggregated columns.

Comment: Now that the keys are identified, do you have a reason **not** to `JOIN` the two tables in some manner?

Comment: @PM77-1 No, i do not.

Answer (score 0):

The Inner Join solved the issue.

```
select inventario.cod as 'Código', sum(inventario.can) as 'Cantidad', inventario.cve as 'Clave', prueba.nom as 'Descripción', prueba.tip as 'Modelo', prueba.pre as 'Precio'
from inventario
INNER JOIN prueba on inventario.cod = prueba.cod
where inventario.loc = 'XTORR' 
group by inventario.cod
order by inventario.cod;
```

Thank you for shedding light on, PM 77-1.